# How do I remove function (handle_new_user) from auth?

Tags: supabase

[image that shows auth functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt7ap.png)
I tried to create a function that creates a user in another table when a user is inserted in auth users but did not go and now because of this function (I think) I cannot create the user . This error occurs (Failed to create user: Database error creating new user)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, instead of using UI I went to SQL Editor and ran this `drop function if exists public.handle_new_user();`

Comment: I had to add `cascade` keyword at the end to be able to delete it